# Arduino Uno, multiple processes, multi-threading

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I´m facing a problem with an application in Arduino Uno.

The board has a sensor that its counting products every second, after some time it sends the number of products to the server however this process takes more than a second, so the code that it is registering the products is not called until this process is completed so a piece of product sometimes is not counted.

I´ve been looking if Arduino supports multi-threading in order to have a thread for sending data to the server and the other one for registering the number of products, but i have no clear answer so far.

What would be the best solution to face this problem?

```
const long MAX_ITERATION = 100000;
const int OFF = 1;
const int ON = 0;
const int PHOTOELECTRIC_SENSOR = 3;

int counter = 0;
long iteration = 0;
int state = OFF;

void loop() {
    registerProduct();
    if (iteration >= MAX_ITERATION) {
         // this process takes more than a second
         sendDataToServer();
         iteration = 0;
    }
    iteration++;
}

void registerProduct() {
    int currentSensorState = digitalRead(PHOTOELECTRIC_SENSOR);
    if (currentSensorState != state) {
        if (currentSensorState == ON) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    state = currentSensorState;
}

void sendDataToServer() {
   // Sends data through HTTP protocol, and sets counter to zero
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might want to redesign this. While you might want to use something like threading on a desktop platform you don't have any hardware support for concurrency in that manner on the Arduino UNO. You do however have interrupts which you can use for your current problem.

Put the sensor on a pin change interrupt. Increment the counter in the ISR for that pin change interrupt. Arduino UNO has a few general purpose pin change interrupts, look at the datasheet for more info.

Then create a timer by using one of the internal timers. Attach this to an interrupt, when the timer interrupt fires take the counter amount and then put this aside. You will need to then send that value over to the server. Try to make the send not block. You may need to service the send in the main loop over multiple loop cycles.

By using the interrupts, especially the timing ones, you will free up a lot of processor cycles. Try to keep the amount of code in each of the ISRs as minimal as possible so that you don't lose data from interrupts being missed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i´m gonna try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concurrency in the microcontroller hardware or the language.

The correct way to do this is use an `interrupt` to accept the updates form the sensor asynchronously.

You should also not block on the send, you should send a few bytes and then send a few more on every loop through.

Answer (score 0):

Using interrupts would be the preferred method, but you can also get away with using a simple or timed scheduler.

I've been working on a project that required one a while ago and you can find the [source code here](https://bitbucket.org/muraleen/project-neutrino/src/0cb37517e6542fb7a276303db1335c4a685637d6/src/kernel/scheduler/?at=master). It's based on a more extensive queuing library by Zuph called [AVRQueue](https://github.com/Zuph/AVRQueue).

A simple implementation of the Scheduler library. I originally wrote it to be compiled with an avr-c compiler and haven't testing it with the arduino IDE but it shouldn't be an issue.

```
Scheduler m();

void setup() {
    m.addTask(querySensor, "q_sens", 0, 1000);
    m.addTask(doStuffWithData, "stuff", 0, 5000);
}

void loop() {
    m.run(millis());
}

int querySensor(unsigned long now) {
    ...
}

int doStuffWithData(unsigned long now) {
    ...
}
```